# Stopping an Amazon RDS DB Instance Temporarily

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is there a way to create a cron job in AWS that automatically starts / stops the DB everyday ?

Comment: Yes there is. Is that all you wanted to know?

Comment: Keep in mind you can stop it, but after 7 days it will get started again: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-rds-supports-stopping-and-starting-of-database-instances/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AWS Lambda Scheduled Events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) to start and stop the RDS Server writing code using AWS SDK for RDS. You can use [startDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#startDBInstance-property) and [stopDBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#stopDBInstance-property) methods. Following example shows how to stop the DB instance using AWS SDK for NodeJS.

```
var params = {
  DBInstanceIdentifier: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  DBSnapshotIdentifier: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
rds.stopDBInstance(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```